# excel custom number formatting - only show decimals when there are not whole numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

Is it possible to format numbers (or currency) in Excel so that there will only be a period when there is not a whole number? For example:

12.43 will appear as 12.43
12 will appear as 12 and not 12.00

Rather than using "General" formatting, I am looking for a way to build on top of the custom format that I am already using: `$0.##,,"m";$-0.##,,"m"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by first formatting the numbers to show the two decimal places and then apply a conditional format to format the the whole numbers. A formula like this will find the whole numbers:

```
=IF(A1-INT(A1)=0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: in case anyone reading has not heard of conditional formatting: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx